# Is this a complete sentence that can work in a paragraph?

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence complete?

> A kid realizing he had a love for a genderless person named science and an obsession with curiosity.

If that sentence was in the middle of a paragraph, would it make sense without adding anything to it? I told my friends this sentence only had a subject and was missing a predicate. But they said that "realizing" is the predicate. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: syntactically that is simply a noun phrase, one that governs no finite verb. It is not a sentence in the sense of a subject and a predicate.

*Realizing* is a nonfinite inflection of the verb *realize*. Finite inflections would be such things as *realizes* and *realized*.

You can think of it as parsing this way:

```
A kid (who is realizing
         that 
          (he had 
                  (a love for a genderless person (who was named science)) 
              and (an obsession with curiosity)
          )   
      )
```

Which works out to just a kid for the subject and no verb to go with it.

You would need to add something like *gets an idea* or *decides to try harder* or *leaves* or *was undecided* to the end of all that so that there’s an actual finite verb representing the kid’s action or condition.

Or just change *realizing* into *realizes* or *has realized* or some such: the kid realizes such and such. Voilà, a sentence!

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, in the intended meaning, it's not a sentence, but a noun phrase. However, it *can* be parsed into a meaningful sentence, just not the one intended.

> [A kid realizing he had a love for a genderless person] [named] [science and an obsession with curiosity].

The way this works is if "named" is a simple past verb, rather than a past participle. In that case, "A kid realizing he had a love for a genderless person" is the subject, "named" is the verb, and "science and an obsession with curiosity" is the object of "named".

This could be meaningful in a context like this:

> When asked to name two things associated with Richard Feynman, a kid realizing he had a love for a genderless person named science and an obsession with curiosity.

The relevance of the love for the genderless person isn't clear but the grammar and meaning are.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the same as:

> A kid eating food (with some description of the object).

So you say, "Okay, a kid is eating food. Then what or so what? "
So it makes no sense to use it as a sentence.